# How to solve " %GDE-I-WRITEERROR, Cannot exit because of write failure. Reason for failure: 13,GDEPUT+48^GDEPUT,%SYSTEM-E-ENO13, Permission denied"

Tags: mumps

I installed according to instruction latest GT.M release version `6.0-000_linux_i686_pro.tar.gz` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sanchez-gtm.

Before instalation I set `$gtm_log` then went through innstalation. Afterwards I set `$gtm_dist` and added to the PATH I set `$gtmroutines`

I started gtm from parent directory and I was trying to create default Global Directory.

```
GTM>d ^GDE
%GDE-I-GDUSEDEFS, Using defaults for Global Directory
/usr/lib/mumps.gld
```

When using exit command I get this error:

```
GDE> exit
%GDE-I-VERIFY, Verification OK

%GDE-I-GDCREATE, Creating Global Directory file
/usr/lib/mumps.gld
%GDE-I-WRITEERROR, Cannot exit because of write failure.  Reason for failure:    
13,GDEPUT+48^GDEPUT,%SYSTEM-E-ENO13, Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have permission to write to /usr/lib?  You might want to try changing the location of your global directory file and mumps.dat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `$gtmgbldir` before creating the default Global Directory.

For example, `export gtmgbldir="~/mumps.gld"` will result in the Global Directory (and by default, the database file as well) being created in your user's home directory, which is a probably better idea than creating them in `/usr/lib/`.

You should also have a look at the file `$gtm_dist/gtmprofile`.  It can be sourced to create a default environment perfect for learning, but it is also a good source of information to learn which environment variables need/can be defined to what effect.

Comment: I changed gtmgbldir few times but still got same problem after entreing GDE I was getting massage that I'm still working in same directory(/user/lib/..) then I change gtmprofile file and my problems solved itself. Thanks again.